# Foundation Slider: how to figure out if just the value changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-handling, zurb-foundation

I'm using the [Foundation Range Slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html) and would like to listen on the **change-event**, but only when the **value changed**.

Unfortunately two changes are detected on init and everytime the window changes as well.

Example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v74v81et/)):

```
<div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="step: 20;">
  <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>

<script>   
$(document).foundation({
  slider: {
      on_change: function(){
          console.log("changed");
          $("body").append("changed<br/>");
     }
   }
});
</script>
```

I cannot find a event like `onValueChanged`. Any ideas how to solve this issue as clean as possible? I'd like to avoid workarounds.

Comment: That almost seems like a bug. I would raise that with the Foundation devs directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rory McCrossan may be right that this is a bug, but there is an easy workaround. Just keep a variable like `sliderVal` in some broader scope than the callback, and use it to track the slider's most recent value. When the `on_change` event fires, check whether the slider value - `$('div.range-slider').attr('data-slider')` - is different from the previously saved value. If not, do nothing; but if the values differ then perform whatever actions you want and make sure to update the `sliderVal` to the new value.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e5q133L/1/) that implements this concept. You'll see it doesn't have any problems with duplicate events or events triggered when the browser window changes.

Also, if you're concerned about keeping `sliderVal` out of global scope, you can hide it inside a closure. That's my preferred approach to avoiding global variables; I made another jsFiddle to demonstrate it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5e5q133L/4/) This version also doesn't fire the event when the window first loads, so I think it solves all your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the slider in this project:

[yearinfocus.gettyimages.com](http://yearinfocus.gettyimages.com)

and I used this to track its changes:

```
$('[data-slider]').on('change.fndtn.slider', callback);
```

In my code I cached the slider element like this:

```
s.slider.$main = $('.range-slider.')
```

in my call back I checked the value of the slider like this:

```
if(!isNaN(parseInt(s.slider.$main.attr('data-slider')-1))){
    var sliderIndex = parseInt(s.slider.$main.attr('data-slider')-1); //zero based
}
```